# WooCommerce Variation Swatches and Photos - get attribute thumbnail

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic, thumbnails, customization

I am using the plugin WooCommerce Variation Swatches and Photos which lets me add a thumbnail to my product's attributes.

I need to list all the attributes on a template and I would like to also get and show the thumbnail.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_texture',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    print_r($term);
}
```

The thumbnail feature is not default in WooCommerce so when I print_r $term there is no thumbnail URL:

```
WP_Term Object
(
[term_id] => 54
[name] => Guilin
[slug] => guilin
[term_group] => 0
[term_taxonomy_id] => 54
[taxonomy] => pa_texture
[description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla imperdiet facilisis convallis.
[parent] => 0
[count] => 2
[filter] => raw
[meta_value] => 0
)
```

How can I get the attribute's thumbnail image?

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Yes, I used get_woocommerce_term_meta. I will answer the question with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using `get_woocommerce_term_meta`

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_texture',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'pa_texture_swatches_id_photo', true );
    $textureImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $textureImg[0]; ?>">
endforeach;
```

Comment: it not giving me the thumbnail image

Comment: My code is `$terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'pa_brand_swatches_id_photo', true );
            $textureImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' ); 
            var_dump( $textureImg);

        endforeach;`